# Баня и банка — однокоренные или нет?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Интересно, слова "баня" и "банка" только похожи или имеют общий корень?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ни странно - да. Во всяком случае это наиболее правдоподобная версия. Оба слова первоначально означали "ванна", потом значения разделились. Правда, в отношении "банки" возможет и вариант более позднего заимствования (из польского, например), но опять-таки от слова, родственного "бане". Т.е. и в этом случае имеет место некоторая условная родственность. *условная потому, что обычно слова, пришедшие в язык-мишень разными путями не считаются в нем родственными, даже если они родственны в языке-источнике.*

I ба́нка I. 1. "скамейка на гребных судах", 2. "песчаная отмель". И то и другое заимств. из нем. Bank – то же, согласно Горяеву 1, ЭС 11. Возм., скорее из голл. bank; см. Мёлен, 28. •• 1 Автор неточен: у Горяева указанная этимология отсутствует. - Прим. ред.

II ба́нка II. 1. " сосуд для консервирования", 2. "медицинская банка", ср. укр. ба́ня " сосуд, купол", ба́нька "медицинская банка", словен. bȃnja " ванна", чеш. báně ж. " сосуд, кувшин", baňka "медицинская банка", польск. bania "пузатый сосуд", bańka "медицинская банка", в.-луж. bańka "все округлое; кувшин", н.-луж. banja " кувшин". Слово первонач., вероятно, идентичное слову ба́ня (см. ниже), которое развило сначала знач. " ванна", затем " сосуд"; см. Бернекер 1, 43; Мурко, WuS 5, 1 и сл.; Зеленин, ЖСт. 22, 438 и сл.; Брандт, РФВ 21, 205. Заимствование ба́нка "медицинская банка" из польск. bańka (Врюкнер 45, 26) невозможно доказать. Вернекер (1, 43) указывает, что лат. balneum имеет знач. " ванна", а франц. bain, ит. bagno означают " баня" и " ванна". Поэтому разграничение у Преобр. (1, 15) слов ба́нка и ба́ня вряд ли верно. "Кровопускание производилось после мытья в бане" – Мерингер, WuS 4, 196.

Фасмер.

Привожу статьи на оба значения, ибо первое часто смешивают со вторым для обоснования якобы различной этимологии баня и банка II (сосуд).

Answer (score 0):

В словообразовательном словаре сказано, что в слове "банка" корень "банк". Кого смущает корень в слове "баночка" ("баноч"), тому напоминают о чередованиях согласных. А в корне "банк" гласная О выпала.

Comment: >>В словообразовательном словаре  

Школьном, Шанского?
Да, с современных позиций это так. Но автор явно интересовался историческим корнем, т.е. родственностью слов.